# How to deactivate a button in android

Tags: java, android, xml, button

I'm making a simple tip calculator app in android and I've got all of the functionality working, but I'm stuck on trying to fix a bug that I've found.  Currently what happens is you enter a number into an `EditText` and choose a service rating from a `Spinner`.  Then you have 2 buttons, one that says `What's my tip?` and one that says `What's my total with tip?` (each are self-explanatory as to what they do).  The bug that I've found is that if you click either button with the `EditText` being empty, it crashes the app.  I've tried `button.setclickable(false/true)` and `button.isClickable()` and `button.isEnabled()` but none of them have worked.  Maybe I did use the correct one but just didn't use it correctly but I've got no idea what to do.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. sorry the XML code is not 100% properly formatted but it's all there

Java code:

```
public void calculateTip (View view)
{
    String tip = et.getText().toString();

    if(tip.isEmpty())
    {
        btn_tip.setClickable(false);
    }
    else
    {
        btn_tip.setClickable(true);
    }

    double finalTip = Double.parseDouble(tip);

    String oneTipFormat = String.format("%.2f", finalTip * 0.10);
    String fourTipFormat = String.format("%.2f", finalTip * 0.13);
    String sixTipFormat = String.format("%.2f", finalTip * 0.15);
    String eightTipFormat = String.format("%.2f", finalTip * 0.20);
    String tenTipFormat = String.format("%.2f", finalTip * 0.25);

    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    String rate = String.valueOf(spin.getSelectedItem());

    if(rate.equals("1 star") || rate.equals("2 stars") || rate.equals("3 stars"))
    {
        String text = "Your rating of: " + rate + " means your tip should be: $" + oneTipFormat;
        textView.setText(text);
    }

    if(rate.equals("4 stars") || rate.equals("5 stars"))
    {
        String text = "Your rating: " + rate + " means your tip should be: $" + fourTipFormat;
        textView.setText(text);
    }

    if(rate.equals("6 stars") || rate.equals("7 stars"))
    {
        String text = "Your rating: " + rate + " means your tip should be: $" + sixTipFormat;
        textView.setText(text);
    }

    if(rate.equals("8 stars") || rate.equals("9 stars"))
    {
        String text = "Your rating: " + rate + " means your tip should be: $" + eightTipFormat;
        textView.setText(text);
    }

    if(rate.equals("10 stars"))
    {
        String text = "Your rating: " + rate + " means your tip should be: $" + tenTipFormat;
        textView.setText(text);
    }
}

public void calculateTotal(View v)
{
    String value = et.getText().toString();
    double finalValue = Double.parseDouble(value);

    String onePriceFormat = String.format("%.2f", finalValue + (finalValue * 0.10));
    String fourPriceFormat = String.format("%.2f", finalValue + (finalValue * 0.13));
    String sixPriceFormat = String.format("%.2f", finalValue + (finalValue * 0.15));
    String eightPriceFormat = String.format("%.2f", finalValue + (finalValue * 0.20));
    String tenPriceFormat = String.format("%.2f", finalValue + (finalValue * 0.25));

    tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    String rating = String.valueOf(spin.getSelectedItem());

    if(rating.equals("1 star") || rating.equals("2 stars") || rating.equals("3 stars"))
    {
        String text = "Based on your service rating of '" + rating + "', your total with tip should be: $" + onePriceFormat;
        tv.setText(text);
    }

    if(rating.equals("4 stars") || rating.equals("5 stars"))
    {
        String text = "Based on your service rating of '" + rating + "', your total with tip should be: $" + fourPriceFormat;
        tv.setText(text);
    }

    if(rating.equals("6 stars") || rating.equals("7 stars"))
    {
        String text = "Based on your service rating of '" + rating + "', your total with tip should be: $" + sixPriceFormat;
        tv.setText(text);
    }

    if(rating.equals("8 stars") || rating.equals("9 stars"))
    {
        String text = "Based on your service rating of '" + rating + "', your total with tip should be: $" + eightPriceFormat;
        tv.setText(text);
    }

    if(rating.equals("10 stars"))
    {
        String text = "Based on your service rating of '" + rating + "', your total with tip should be: $" + tenPriceFormat;
        tv.setText(text);
    }
}
```

My XML code:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_total_price"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/what_is_the_total_price"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_bill"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/enter_your_bill_here"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_service"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/rate_your_service_using_the_drop_down_menu_below"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_rating"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/rating"
    android:prompt="@string/service_prompt">
</Spinner>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_tip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/what_s_my_tip"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_margin="25dp"
    android:onClick="calculateTip"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_tip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_total"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/what_s_my_total_with_tip"
    android:onClick="calculateTotal"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_price"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/clear"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:onClick="clear"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The problem is probably due to this `double finalTip = Double.parseDouble(tip);`. Try putting an if-clause checking if tip is not empty. Otherwise finalTip gets the value 0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that you're disabling the click of the button on the click handler :) In order to disable the button you need to execute the logic so it will fail when `et` is empty.

If you want to connect `et` value with enabling/disabling click button, you'll have to use `TextChangedListener` to detect current EditText value.

Also, if I understand correctly, you're button should start with disabled since the initial value for `et` is not valid to calculate the tip.

Another option instead of disabling button is to add an `if` condition at the very beginning of `calculateTip`. If `et` is empty, you show a message and return without executing any other code